# SelectList try to import List<SelectListItem> error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlist, selectlistitem

I couldnt understand one thing I have a List of SelectList Items

```
List<SelectListItem> selectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

and when I try to put it inside a SelectList object like

```
sl = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text");
```

one of selected attribute in selectList "true" automatically updated to false!(Before put this "List" its selected is "true") Moreover I tried

```
sl = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text",selectList.Single(i=>i.Value == id));
```

also it couldnt make that item "Selected = true" either?

What might be problem? I know 'Id' of the item which should be selected. But I cant make it selected.

Thanks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `List< SelectListItem>` then why are you again creating `List< SelectListItem>`, you can just use that, passing it to `SelectList` is useless IMO.

and in `SelectList`  for setting selected, you could do this way:

```
sl = new SelectList(selectList, "Value", "Text",selectList.First(i=>i.Value == id).Value);
```

Comment: Thanks the second one worked "Value". And I will try the first one Im just learning . Thanks again :)